# UNIX: find the files used by other users

Tags: unix

UNIX:
How to find the number of users who have a given file in their home directory?? 
As in how can we access the files being used by other users.the command required for that.
I tried find command and all extensions of who

Comment: You tried `who` in order to find files?

Comment: did you try something like this :  find . ! -user name ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the users' home directories are under `/home` and your're trying to find all users that have a file `foo.txt`, you can use this find command:

```
find /home -name "foo.txt" -exec bash -c "IFS=/ && read -a arr <<< {} && echo ${arr[2]}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have root privilege and assuming foo.txt is in the home directory, not a subdirectory thereof:

```
sudo find /home -maxdepth 2 -name "foo.txt" | wc -l
```

will give you the user count and

```
sudo find /home -maxdepth 2 -name "foo.txt" -printf "%u\n"
```

will give you a list of their names (assuming each foo.txt is owned by the owner of the home directory it is found in).